# How can I make "true normals" geometry node output relative to object local space?

Tags: node-editor

That is whole question. Now it is relative to World orientation, but I want it to be relative to object orientation.
Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a vector transform node:

[image]

I need to write 30 characters to post though.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I absolutely forgot about the existence of that node.